# How do I use @Parcelize with createTypedArray(Creator)?

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, kotlin-android-extensions, parcel

I've started using the Kotlin `@Parcelize` annotation on my Kotlin `Parcelable` classes and I love it, but then I can't include them as members of Java `Parcelable`s. Specifically it can't find the `CREATOR` member of my Kotlin class.

```
@Parcelize data class Foo { val whatever: Any }
```

```
public class Bar implements Parcelable {
    public Foo foo;

    private Bar(Parcel in) {
        foo = in.createTypedArray(Foo.CREATOR); <-- Foo.CREATOR not found
```

Is there a way around this or do I have to manually implement `Parcelable` in `Foo`?

Comment: Convert `Bar` to Kotlin! :-)